# C# .NET Core DbContext not returning data that is in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dbcontext

I have the following code:

```
public void someMethod(){
    ...

    var accounts = myRepo.GetAccounts(accountId)?.ToList(); 

    ...

    foreach (var account in accounts)
    {
        account.Status="INACTIVE";
        var updatedAccount = myRepo.AddOrUpdateAccounts(account);
    }
}

public Account AddOrUpdateAccounts(Account account){
    //I want to compare account in the Db and what is passed in. So get the account from DB
    var accountFromDb = myRepo.GetAccounts(account.Id); //this doesn't return whats in the database.

    //here accountFromDb.Status is returned as INACTIVE, but in the database the column value is ACTIVE
    ...
    ...
}

public IEnumerable<Account> GetAccounts(int id){
    return id <= 0 ? null : m_Context.Accounts.Where(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Here, inside `someMethod()` I am calling `GetAccounts()` that returns data from the Accounts table.

Then I am changing the `Status` of the account, and calling `AddOrUpdateAccounts()`.

Inside `AddOrUpdateAccounts()`, I want to compare the account that was passed in and whats in the database. When I call `GetAccounts()`, it returned a record with `STATUS="INACTIVE"`. I haven't done `SaveChanges()`. Why didn't `GetAccounts()` returned the data from the database? In the Db the status is still "ACTIVE"

Comment: Try returning `m_Context.Accounts.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToList();`

Comment: Re the often more than one account with the same id? It feels like GetAccounts should just return a single account or a null, via SingleOrDefault, no?

Comment: "here account.Status is returned as INACTIVE, but in the database the column value is ACTIVE" - ORMs will often hand you the same reference every time they see the same id for a given collection, rather than deserialize the data (or even fetch it) each time - is this what you are seeing? i.e. it is simply handing you back the same object that you already edited

Comment: @MarcGravell since I updated the Status to INACTIVE, I updated the ORMs reference. Therefore, when I called GetAccounts again for the same id, it didnt fetch it from the DB, it just gave me the reference. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly, yes. Note that it isn't always possible for it to avoid the fetch (although `{First|Single}[OrDefault]` will usually spot it before issuing a query), but even if it does execute: when it comes back it'll say "id 283526 from Accounts? I've already seen that, here it is"

Comment: Why you name both the action parameter and result of query as `account` in ·AddOrUpdateAccounts`?

Comment: @XingZou that was an error. I fixed the question and added comments.

Answer (score 1):

The repository method should return `IQueryable<Account>` rather than `IEnumerable<Account>` as this will allow the the consumer to continue to refine any criteria or govern how the account(s) should be consumed prior to any query executing against the database:

I would consider:

```
public IQueryable<Account> GetAccountsById(int id){
    return m_Context.Accounts.Where(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Don't return #null, just the query. The consumer can decide what to do if the data is not available.

From there the calling code looks like:

```
var accounts = myRepo.GetAccounts(accountId).ToList(); 

foreach (var account in accounts)
{
    account.Status="INACTIVE";
}
```

Your addOrUpdate wouldn't work:

```
public Account AddOrUpdateAccounts(Account account){
    ...
    var account = myRepo.GetAccounts(account.Id); //this doesn't return whats in the database.
```

You pass in the Account as "account" then try declaring a local variable called "account". If you remove the `var` keyword you would load the DbContext's record over top your modified account and your changes would be lost. Loading the account into another variable isn't necessary as long as the account is still associated with the DbContext.

Edit:  After changing the `var account = ...` statement to look like:

```
public Account AddOrUpdateAccounts(Account account){
    ...
    var accountToUpdate = myRepo.GetAccounts(account.Id); //this doesn't return whats
```

`accountToUpdate` will show the modified status rather than what is in the database because that DbContext is still tracking the reference to the entity that you modified.  (`account`) For instance if I do this:

```
var account1st = context.Accounts.Single(x => x.AccountId == 1);
var account2nd = context.Accounts.Single(x => x.AccountId == 1);
Console.WriteLine(account1st.Status); // I get "ACTIVE"
Console.WriteLine(account2nd.Status); // I get "ACTIVE"
account1st.Status = "INACTIVE";
Console.WriteLine(account2nd.Status); // I get "INACTIVE"
```

Both references point to the same instance. It doesn't matter when I attempt to read the Account the 2nd time, as long as it's coming from the same DbContext and the context is tracking instances. If you read the row via a different DbContext, or use `AsNoTracking()` with all of your reads then the account can be read fresh from the database. You can reload an entity, but if those variables are pointing at the same reference it will overwrite your changes and set the entity back to `Unmodified`. This can be a little confusing when watching an SQL profiler output because in some cases you will see EF run a `SELECT` query for an entity, but the entity returned has different, modified values than what is in the database. Even when loading from the tracking cache, EF can still execute queries against the DB in some cases, but it returns the tracked entity reference.

/Edit

When it comes to saving the changes, it really just boils down to calling the SaveChanges on the DbContext that the account is associated. The "tricky" part is scoping the DbContext so that this can be done. The recommended pattern for this is the Unit of Work. There are a few different ones out there, and the one I recommend for EF is Mehdime's DbContextScope, however you can implement simpler ones that may be easier to understand and follow.  Essentially a unit of work encapsulates the DbContext so that you can define a scope that repositories can access the same DbContext, then commit those changes at the end of the work.

At the most basic level:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork<TDbContext> : IDisposable where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    TDbContext Context { get; } 

    int SaveChanges();
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork<YourDbContext>
{
    private YourDbContext _context = null;
    TDbContext IUnitOfWork<YourDbContext>.Context
    {
        get { return _context ?? (_context = new YourDbContext("YourConnectionString"); }
    }

    int IUnitOfWork<YourDbContext>.SaveChanges()
    {
        if(_context == null)
            return 0;
       return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    { 
        try
        {
           if (_context != null)
              _context.Dispose();
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        { }
    }
}
```

With this class available, and using dependency injection via an IoC container (Autofac, Unity, or MVC Core) you register the unit of work as Instance per Request so that when the controller and repository classes request one in their constructor, they receive the same instance.

Controller / Service:

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork<YourDbContext> _unitOfWork = null;
private readonly IYourRepository _repository = null;

public YourService(IUnitOfWork<YourDbContext> unitOfWork, IYourRepository repository)
{
   _unitOfWork = unitOfWork ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("unitOfWork");
   _repository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
}
```

Repository

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork<YourDbContext> _unitOfWork = null;

public YourService(IUnitOfWork<YourDbContext> unitOfWork)
{
   _unitOfWork = unitOfWork ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("unitOfWork");
}

private YourDbContext Context { get { return _unitOfWork.Context; } }
```

Big Disclaimer: This is a very crude initial implementation to explain roughly how a Unit of Work can operate, it is no way production suitable code. It has limitations, specifically around disposing the DbContext but should serve as a demonstration. Definitely look to implement a library that's already out there and addresses these concerns. These implementations properly manage the DbContext disposal and will manage a scope beyond the context, like a TransactionScope so that their SaveChanges is required even if the unitOfWork.Context.SaveChanges() is called.

With a unit of work available to the Controller/Service and Repository, the code to use the repository and update your changes becomes:

```
var accounts = myRepo.GetAccountsById(accountId).ToList(); 
foreach (var account in accounts)
{
    account.Status="INACTIVE";
}

UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

With a proper unit of work it will look more like:

```
using (var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
{
    var accounts = myRepo.GetAccountsById(accountId).ToList(); // Where myRepo can resolve the unit of work via locator.
    foreach (var account in accounts)
    {
        account.Status="INACTIVE";
    }

    unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
}
```

This way if you were to call different repos to fetch data, perform a number of different updates, the changes would be committed all in one call at the end and rolled back if there was a problem with any of the data.

Comment: The variable names in AddOrUpdateAccounts was an error. I modified the questions and added some notes.

Comment: You don't need to implement `IDisposable` explicitly in ASP.NET Core. Because it is the responsibility of the DI container to dispose the object correctly. So you can safely remove `IDisposable` from your `UnitOfWork`.

Comment: That unit of work example is for demonstration only. If a DI were to provide a DbContext to a UoW then the DI would manage disposal. In that example though the DbContext is new'd up inside the UoW so the UoW must be disposable to ensure the DbContext is disposed as well. DI would dispose the UoW dependency only.

Comment: @nmess88 - The reason that your attempt to retrieve the data again from the database is showing "Inactive" is because that DbContext is still tracking the reference to the entity that you modified. I added an edit above explaining that behaviour.